# Issue with laravel app on web hosting 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found

Tags: php, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I uploaded my laravel project to public_html of cpanel . and then moved the contents of public folder of laravel app to a directory above . And changed the location in index.php

```
require __DIR__.'/./vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/./bootstrap/app.php';
```

But, I was getting a error 500 message with the message "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found" in app.php of bootstrap folder.

I tried clearing cache , but it did not work .
Please help me in resolving this issue

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong.

Upload the content of your project to `public_html/` and then, set the `document root` from the server to the folder `public_html/public`.

Don't move the files inside `public/`.

Comment: It is still the same error ! How to solve the issue with the bootstrap folder.